# Gnuplot: Is it possible to store variables in an array using a for-loop?

Tags: arrays, gnuplot

Let's assume we got the following variables:

```
var1 = 2
var2 = 8
var3 = 24
```

I want to do the following, just as a loop:

```
array A[3]
A[1] = var1
A[2] = var2
A[3] = var3
```

what i tried but did not work:

```
array A[3]
do for [i=1:3] {
A[i] = var[i]
}
```

I wanted to add the index from `i` to the `variable` so that it'll be `A[1] = var1` etc. It says the variable `var` would be undefined.
Round brackets like `var(i)` don't work either.

Is there even a possibility to do so?
Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Check `help evaluate`. Maybe there are better ways.

**Code:**

```
### assign variables to array
reset session

var1 = 2
var2 = 8
var3 = 24

array A[3]

do for [i=1:3] {
    eval(sprintf("A[%d] = var%d",i,i))
}

print A
### end of code
```

**Result:**

```
[2,8,24]
```